# Missing udhcpc in /sbin in busybox-1.29

Tags: linux, embedded-linux, buildroot, busybox

I'm using `buildroot-2017` with `busybox-1.26.2` to build filesystem image for my embedded board using Linux kernel and `udhcpc` still work fine. But when I change to use `buildroot-2019` with `busybox-1.29.3`, I can't see `udhcpc` in `/sbin` anymore, also the script `/usr/share/udhcpc/default.script` is disappear too. Does anyone tell me what happen with that and how to enable `udhcpc`?

Comment: I guess you have to enable it in the configuration file.

Comment: Please be specific, buildroot releases follow a `<year>.<month>[.<bugfix>]` scheme, so there is no 2017 or 2019 releases. Given the version numbers, I take it you mean 2017.02.`<something>` and 2019.02.`<something>`. More importantly, how does your .config look like? With 2019.02.3 and a trivial defconfig, the files are there as expected.

Comment: Thank for your comment, I solved this, I just take care about .config in buildroot, but forgot to enable in busybox.config in package/busybox